# Open a local document with Microsoft Office Word from javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-word

My problem is simple, consider a word document available in 
"C:\TestDocument.docx"
all I want is a command from my javascript website to open this document with Microsoft Office Word application ( I do not want to render the document on a browser), how can I achieve this ? I read that a browser cannot give a command to run an application but then I tried Office URI Schemes and tried to open like this:

```
function openURI() {
var urlToLaunch = "ms-word:ofe|u|file:///C:/TestDocument.docx";
if (navigator.msLaunchUri) {
  navigator.msLaunchUri(urlToLaunch);
} else {
  var win = (window.parent) ? window.parent : window;
  win.location.assign(urlToLaunch);
}
```

}

But I get the error "this action couldn't be performed because office doesn't recognize the command it was given".

Am I on the right path ? or should I consider another solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You can launch other software from the browser, but you can't launch a software with files from the user's hard drive. Browsers don't have the permission to do this. It would be extremely insecure to allow browsers this level of access to the system.